# PDO and ajax call

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, pdo

I am new to PHP-PDO and need some assistance. My application routes all controllers to the `index.php` though a `routes.php` file. For example, when my sign-up form is submitted the form is handled `action=index.php?controller=signup&action=createuser`. The `routes.php` computes this creates a `new signupcontroller($_POST)` object and calls `createuser()`. Once the user is created a welcome page is `required_once`, which, with javascript, I build a grid of check-boxes. After the check-boxes are built with jquery `onchange` that makes a ajax call, or supposed to create an ajax, but does not work.

The url is suppose to send params with it to change the controller and action in order to call an appropriate function, and store the check-box option. However, when I check the box nothing happens.

ajax call:

```
  $('#interests').on('change', 'input', function (e){
      e.preventDefault();
      var str = $('#interests').serialize();

      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url:  'index.php?controller=interest&action=set_user_interest',
        async:  true,
        traditional: true,
        data: str,
        success:  function (msg) {
          console.log(msg);

        }
      });
    });
```

routes.php

```
function call($controller, $action){
 require_once('controllers/' . $controller . '_controller.php');

    // create a new instance of the needed controller
    switch($controller) {
        case 'interest':
        require_once 'models/interest.php';
        $controller = new InterestController();
    }

    // call the action
    $controller->{ $action }();
}
// just a list of the controllers we have and their actions
// we consider those "allowed" values
$controllers = array(
                      'interest'=>['set_user_interest', 'error']
                    );

// check that the requested controller and action are both allowed
// if someone tries to access something else he will be redirected to the error action of the pages controller
if (array_key_exists($controller, $controllers)) {
  if (in_array($action, $controllers[$controller])) {
    call($controller, $action);
  } else {
    call('landing', 'error');
  }
} else {
  call('landing', 'error');
}
```

index.php

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once('greenCupOfWater.inc');
if (isset($_GET['controller']) && isset($_GET['action'])) {
    $controller = $_GET['controller'];
    $action     = $_GET['action'];
  } else {
    $controller = 'landing';
    $action     = 'landing_page';
  }

require_once 'views/layout.php';
 ?>
```

layout.php

```
    <html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1">
    <title>Witit</title>
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="../images/icons/favicon-32x32.png">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/5.0.0/normalize.min.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Work+Sans:100" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/master.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/welcome.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href='stylesheets/<?php echo $controller ?>.css'>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js" integrity="sha256-DZAnKJ/6XZ9si04Hgrsxu/8s717jcIzLy3oi35EouyE=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <?php include 'routes.php'; ?>
    <script src="scripts/main.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="scripts/modalHelper.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

javascript files:

```
  function build_interest(it, src){
  var intrst = it;
  var htag = it+"-header";
  //var chng = 'this.form.submit()';

  var ctr = document.createElement('div');
  ctr.setAttribute('class', 'interest_container');

  var lbl = document.createElement('label');
  lbl.setAttribute('for', intrst);

  var img = document.createElement('img');
  img.setAttribute('src', src);

  var title = document.createElement('h2');
  title.setAttribute('id', htag);

  var inp_f =document.createElement('input');
  inp_f.setAttribute('type', 'hidden');
  inp_f.setAttribute('name', intrst);
  inp_f.setAttribute('value', 0);

  var inp = document.createElement('input');
  inp.setAttribute('type', 'checkbox');
  inp.setAttribute('id', intrst);
  inp.setAttribute('name', intrst);
  inp.setAttribute('value', 1);

  lbl.appendChild(img);
  ctr.appendChild(lbl);
  ctr.appendChild(inp_f);
  ctr.appendChild(inp);
  ctr.appendChild(title);

  var elem = document.getElementById('interests');
  elem.appendChild(ctr);

  document.getElementById(htag).innerHTML = it;
}
function myFunc(obj) {
  var num = 0;
  for (var src in obj) {
    if ((obj.hasOwnProperty(src))&&(obj[num].Interests_Pix!==null)) {
      build_interest(obj[num].Interests, obj[num].Interests_Pix);
    }
    ++num;
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you be more specific with regards to *nothing happens.*? When you look in the network tab of the console, is the request being sent? If so, what is the response?

Comment: Also, you may need to show us the form with the `'#interests'` element. It may just be a typo in the click handler for example.

Comment: It's going to be hard for anyone to say for certain what's going wrong with the information given.  I would start with making sure the browser is sending what you expect it to (dump it to a file from your php script).  If that is correct then make sure the scripts are returning/echoing what you expect from that input.  If that works make sure the browser is receiving the message in the form you expect.  If you can't find the problem after that update your question with your findings and I'm sure someone will be able to figure it out.

Comment: @DelightedD0D The network says stalled

Comment: @DelightedD0D i just added the javascript functions that check and build the grids